# Calling a batch script from a vbscript script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, call

I am trying to call a batch file from VBS, but I keep getting this "object required" error:

> Line: 4
>   Char: 1
>   Error: Object Required: 'wshshell'
>   Code: 800A01A8

VBS just won't let me call it, no matter what I do. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
X=MsgBox("Scan For Malware?",vbYesNo,"InSYS AntiVirus")
if x=6 Then

wshshell.run "InSys AntiVirus.bat"

End if

if x=7 Then
wscript.quit

end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you have not created any object named **wshshell**.

To run a CMD batch file from VBScript:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "InSys AntiVirus.bat"
```

Source: http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-run.html